# IntelliJ style comment block cannot be recognized

Tags: comment

In java-mode, I find the IntelliJ style comment block `/** ... */` cannot be recognized correctly. And I have checked that the value of `comment-start-skip` variable (inherit from c-mode) is set as
`"\\(//+\\|/\\*+\\)\\s *"`, which is supposed to match `/**` in first line. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found that starting with `/**` is a convention for [javadoc comment](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#format). As opposed to the plain comment's `font-lock-comment-face`, we can do highlight customization with [`font-lock-doc-face`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces-for-Font-Lock.html).